# Tkinter constant LabelFrame width and height

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

is there a way to set a width and height on a labelframe in tkinter, because if i enter a specific height and width when i create the labelframe, effectively, it take the correct value, but only if the frame is empty.
Else if I place something in, the label frame take the height and the width of the object with margin.

```
serverlabel = tk.LabelFrame(root, text="Servers",bg="#11ba71",relief="solid", width=320, height=430,padx=5,pady=5)
serverlabel.place(x=320,y=0)
```

serverlabel is empty, and it have the good size :

[image: here the size is correct]

```
optionlabel = tk.LabelFrame(root, text="Options",bg="#11ba71",relief="solid",width=200, height=50,padx=5,pady=5)
optionlabel.grid(column=0, row=3, sticky=tk.W)

settingsbutton = tk.Button(optionlabel, text="Paramètre", command=parameter)
settingsbutton.pack()
...
```

but here, optionlabel is only 112x107px instead of 200x50 :

[image]

Could you help me please ?

Comment: If you put the buttons inside `optionlabel` using `pack()`, then call `optionlabel.pack_propagate(0)` after `optionlabel.grid(...)`.  But then you cannot see all the buttons because the height is not tall enough to show them.

Comment: @acw1668 but there is a way to set width and height of the label, without care of how in insert object widget inside ?

Comment: Yes you can.  My comment is just based on your posted code.

Comment: @acw1668 So what method i have to considered to insert widget inside ?

Comment: It is up to your design.  As I said in my comment, if you use `pack()`, then you need to call `optionlabel.pack_propagate(0)`.  If you use `grid()`, then you need to call `optionlabel.grid_propagate(0)`.  If you use `place()`, nothing is required.